# How do lambda sensors work?

Tags: o2-sensor

Virtually every modern passenger vehicle today utilizes lambda sensors from the factory.

How critical are they to a vehicle's operation? How do they work?

Answer (score 13):

Lambda sensors, often referred to as *oxygen sensors* or *O2 sensors*, are the bedrock of any modern-day EFI system. Without them, fuel injection management is essentially flying blind and has to resort to other less-desirable means to determine how much air and fuel need to be mixed.

Their primary role is to provide feedback to the fuel management to determine if the air-fuel mixture being fed into the engine is being mixed in the right ratio. They do so by measuring ["lambda"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air%E2%80%93fuel_ratio#Air.E2.80.93fuel_equivalence_ratio_.28.CE.BB.29), the ratio of actual AFR to stoich.

Two lambda sensors sandwiching a catalytic converter can also be used to assess if the cat is running properly.

---

### Lambda sensor types & Operation

Lambda sensors work at elevated temperatures, around 300 °C (600 °F); many lambda sensors contain a resistive heater element to help get them up to temperature quickly.

1. ***Narrowband***

   These *qualitatively* detect whether the exhaust gases are rich or lean.

   The most prevalent type of sensor is the ***zirconia-based*** narrowband, which generates its own voltage as signal output:

   - useful voltage range 0.1 - 0.9 V
   - stoichiometric AFR at 0.45 V
   - *low voltage = lean condition, high voltage = rich condition*

   [image: Narrowband Voltage Graph]

   The rarer ***titania-based*** variant does not generate its own voltage, but changes electrical resistance based on the oxygen concentration detected.

   - *low resistance = rich condition, high resistance = lean condition*
2. ***Wideband***

   These *quantitatively* measure lambda.

   Changes in AFR translate to changes in current output, which is then converted to a corresponding voltage. The voltage range may vary between car manufacturers.

   - *low current = rich condition, high current = lean condition*

   [image: Wideband Sensor Graph]

---

### Impact on fuel management

The diagram below nicely summarizes the impact of lambda sensors on fuel injection management:

- lambda sensor senses leaner-than-desired exhaust → increase injector pulsewidth
- lambda sensor senses richer-than-desired exhaust → decrease injector pulsewidth

[image: Lambda Impact on Fuel Management]

Comment: None of these sensors measure "the oxygen content" of the exhaust, that varies with combustion efficiency, misfire and similar changes in the combustion chamber, making it useless as a way to determine mixture. They measure fuel mixture using catalytic action combined with oxygen ion transfer through a solid electrolyte.